# How can I prove the series is convergent or divergent or convergent based on a condition

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a condition saying both of these series are convergent:

$\sum a_k$

$\sum \left(a_k+2b_k\right)$

Now how can I prove that

$\sum \left(2a_k-b_k\right)$

will either always converge or always diverge. So based on the current conditions can we say
$2a_k$ will always converge so if $ b_k \le 2a_k$ for all $k$, then the series will always converge as well? Or the series will alwaysconverge even if that condition is not met?

Comment: $$
\sum\limits_{k = 0}^N {(2a_k  - b_k )}  = \frac{5}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^N {a_k }  - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^N {(a_k  + 2b_k )} 
$$

Comment: Hi ashes999. I think Gary's equation is what you need. But I don't think $b_k \leq 2a_k$ is relevant.

Comment: @Gary Oh, I see so that is definitely always convergent correct? Since the sum of two convergent series is always convergent

Comment: @ashes999 Yes, that is correct.